# Is it possible to prevent apps from knowing whether development settings is enabled?

Tags: android

I don't want an app to know that I enabled development settings.
It seems like apps can read this info by doing something like the following:

```
int adb = Settings.Secure.getInt(this.getContentResolver(),
            Settings.Global.DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED , 0);
```

according to [How can I check if Developer options are enabled on Android 4.0.3 for API 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41734808/how-can-i-check-if-developer-options-are-enabled-on-android-4-0-3-for-api-15).

Is it possible to either prevent apps from reading this or pretend I didn't enable develop options?